# Apply a javascript function in span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript function to format numbers with thousands seperator. I have many Span tags with the same class in my HTML code and I want to apply to all of them.

```
<span class="money">here is the number</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
</script>
```

How can I apply the Javascript on every span with this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.text(function(index, text))`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text):

```
$('.money').text(function(index, old_value) {
    return numberWithCommas(old_value);
});
```

The given function is called for each element that matches the selector and its current text value is passed as the second argument; the returned value will become the new text contents.

Answer (score 0):

Get the collection, iterate:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("money");
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].innerHTML = numberWithCommas(spans[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.money').each(function(){
     $(this).text(numberWithCommas($(this).text());  
});
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to set the result to be the text of the element.